# Как в 1С-Битрикс (версия 16) делать другую страницу главной по умолчанию?

Tags: битрикс

Например: Есть страница `http://site.ru/product/`

Как в 1С-Битрикс делать эту страницу главной по умолчанию (чтобы загрузилась так: `http://site.ru/`)?

Comment: Это не вопрос Битрикс, это вопрос редиректа. Это в файле urlrewrite.php или .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

1 Вариант это просто содержание файла `/product/index.php` перенести в `/index.php`

2 Вариант — В `htaccess` прописать

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^$ /products/1 [QSA,L]
```